# Gradient Fill does not Display as Expected when Element is Translated

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I get strange behavior when I translate a raphael element and change the fill gradient at the end of the translation (like might be done to show the object is selected).  If the object is just "clicked" (no translate or drag) the gradient change works fine.  When the object is translated the gradient does not look right.

The issue can be seen in this code:

```
var paper = Raphael('page', '100%', '100%');
var blocks = paper.set();

var base = {"fill": "90-#aaa:5-#fff:95"}    
var selected = {"fill": "90-#a99:5-#faa:95"}    

var r = paper.rect(10 + 200, 10, 100, 50, 10).attr(base);

r.drag(
    function(dx, dy) {
        this.translate(dx-this.ox,dy-this.oy);

        this.ox = dx;
        this.oy = dy;
    },
    function(x, y) {
        this.ox = 0;
        this.oy = 0;      
    },
    function() {
        r.attr(selected);
    }
);
```

**jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/gnarlybear/Lr5fz/

- Drag the box down and it turns mostly grey
- Restart the script,click the box and he gradient seems correct
- Restart, drag the box up
  and it turns red

Is this how it should work (perhaps the gradient is being applied to a broader area)?  If so how can I get the gradient to display when dragging an element?

Answer (score 0):

I narrowed it down some more: http://jsfiddle.net/Lr5fz/16/

Problem occurs when you invoke `translate` then `attr`. For some reason the inverted translation is applied to the `gradientTransform` on the `lineargradient` element.

For further bugtracing start at source lines 722-839: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/raphael.svg.js

Comment: Thank you, I'm relatively new to js so sometimes its a big help just to know the problem is real.  I'll have to dive deeper but probably won't be quick.